# Why does iframe DOM manipulation work from Chrome Dev Console, but not by loading the JS directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

I'm trying to create a button that will automatically fill out an external survey for our clients with default values.
The best approach I came up with was loading it in  and triggering events that would fill the form at load.
I have some understanding of CORS, but what I can't understand is why I can trigger these events from Chrome Dev Console and interact with the `<iframe>`, but can't do it directly from the JS.

This is using HTML and JS. I've tried to access the elements by their position like this, but wont find the element when run from the JS

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[21].click()
```

I expected that it was possible to load some events on top of the iframe, simulating a real user.

Why can I do this from Chrome Dev Console but not from an `.onload()` directly in the JS and are there any workarounds?

Comment: Is the content of the iframe on a different domain to the parent window? If so, then as far as I was aware it shouldn't work in any case (either programmatically or from direct console input)

Comment: IF in Chrome Dev tools you pick from menu the iframe. You will be in context of that iframe like the script that was added to external iframe. But if you select main page, you will not be able to use iframe and get the window.document from it to get element (even in chrome dev tools).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, it is on a different domain. But it works from dev tools, and what I don't understand is why I can't run scripts from parent site that acts in the same manner as run from dev tools.

Comment: Dev tools aside, you will never be able to programmatically amend content of a cross-domain iframe from the parent document for security reasons.

Comment: @jcubic Is there no way to make the parent page access the frame in the same way that dev tools can access the iframe directly?

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan said you can't amend Cross Origin Policy, this would be real security issue. I think that the only way to make this work is Chrome Extensions that can circumvent this limitation, if you give it proper permission (I think in manifest file).